# Getting/Passing Polyline object to geoprocessor as parameter

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcobjects

I want to know how can I get or pass a polyline to a gp tool using ArcObjects. Basically the tool just returns a line created in the gp.

Below is the code which I am using

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject();
    try     
    {

        GeoProcessor gp = new GeoProcessor();

        gp.addToolbox("D:\\gptools\\Toolbox.tbx");

        VarArray arr = new VarArray();

        IGeoProcessorResult res =  gp.execute("LineObject", arr, null);

        if(res.getStatus() == esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
        {
            GPLine v = (GPLine) res.getOutput(0);

            IPolyline poly = null ;

            v.setPolylineByRef(poly);

            obj.put("line", ServerUtilities.getJSONFromPolyline((Polyline) poly));
        }
        else
        {
            obj.put("error", "error");
        }

        return obj.toString().getBytes("utf-8");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ServerUtilities.sendError(500, "Error", null).getBytes();
    }
```

No such interface exception is thrown by below line

```
v.setPolylineByRef(poly)
```

Same happens if I try to pass a line to another gptool. Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: There are easily more than a dozen ways to pass coordinate data between components. You need to decide between direct and indirect, by reference, value, or file, and one of several dozen different formats.